# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code is returning some error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 404 Not Found
>      at _response.transport.request.then (/app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:193:21)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>    (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)

Here's my node.js code:

```
  console.log('Turned on Discord bot');
  bot.user.setActivity(`${bot.users.size} comrades!`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
  bot.channels.get(bot.channels.get(`${mainChatChannelID}`).id).send(`**Resuming processes!** :wave:`)
})

bot.on('message', async message => {

  const args = message.content.split(/[ ]+/)
  const promoLogs = bot.channels.get(`${xpAuditLogChannelID}`)
  const officerRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === `${officerRoleE}`);
  const groupFunction = await bloxyClient.getGroup(groupID)

  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}${xpName}`)){
    if (!message.member.roles.exists("name", `${officerRoleE}`)){
      return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but only users with the **\`${officerRoleE}\`** can run that command!`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
    }
    if (!args[1]){
      return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you're missing the first argument--add or remove?\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
    }else if (args[1].toLowerCase() !== "add" && args[1].toLowerCase() !== "remove"){
      return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you didn't provide me with a correct first argument--add or remove?\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
    }else{
      if (!args[2]){
        return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you're missing the second argument--number of ${xpName}?\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }else if (isNaN(Number(args[2]))){
        return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you didn't provide me with a real number.\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }else if (args[2] < 0){
        return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you need to provide me with a positive number.\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }else if (args[2] > maxXP){
        return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you need to provide mw with a number that's less than the max ${xpName}--currently set at ${maxXP} ${xpName}.\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }else if (!args[3]){
        return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, but you're missing the third argument--the usernames!\n**Adding ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} add 1 username1, username2, username3...\`\nRemoving ${xpName}: \`${prefix}${xpName} remove 1 username1, username2, username3...\`**`).then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }else{
        if (args[1].toLowerCase() === "add"){
          var userArray = message.content.slice(message.content.indexOf(message.content.split(" ")[3])).split(', ');
          for (i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++){
            var { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=${userArray[i]}`);
            if (body.success === false){
              var errorEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor(0xff4040)
                .setDescription(`:warning: **${userArray[i]} doesn't exist on ROBLOX** :warning:`);
                await message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
            }else{
              var userID = await rbx.getIdFromUsername(`${userArray[i]}`);
              var { body } = await snekfetch.get(`${fireBaseURL}/xpData/users/${userID}.json`);
              var currentXP;
```

(sorry it's too long, I can't put it here)

https://pastebin.com/4Q8ShEvJ

Comment: What happens when you manually call `https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=` using postman or your terminal?

Comment: I'm using Heroku as my host.

Comment: And what do you mean by "manually" calling it?

Comment: `curl https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=`

Comment: Or use Postman if you are not on a Unix based system

Comment: It shows {"success":false,"errorMessage":"Invalid username"}, which means with a valid username it should work. I tried it with a valid username and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by
>   rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

I think it says it all, using async await is good but you have to try catch the block, 
Maybe you could try this:

```
try{    
  const groupFunction = await bloxyClient.getGroup(groupID)
  //with the following of your code or encapsulate the rest in a function.
}catch (err){
  return console.log(err)
}
```

maybe for it to work as is :

```
let groupFunction;
try{    
  groupFunction = await bloxyClient.getGroup(groupID)
  //with the following of you code or encapsulate the rest in a function.
}catch (err){
  return console.log(err)
}
```

All your "await" have to be try/catched

Comment: It’s still showing the error even when I fixed it. I replace your answer with my code because there was only one async function in the whole code. It also said something about a promise. I’m new to Javascript, so can you explain where do I find a so-called “promise” in my code so I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: Also I’m very sorry to bother you but if you have some times, please look through my code because the error only shows when I do the command !xp add (number) (username). (xp is in xpName)

Comment: I think you have to try/catch the await functions 
In fact the keyword await abstract the Promise mechanism you could write 

try{    
  const groupFunction = await bloxyClient.getGroup(groupID)
  //with the following of your code or encapsulate the rest in a function.
}catch (err){
  return console.log(err)
}

Or 
  
 const groupFunction = bloxyClient.getGroup(groupID)
.then(()=>{//do something})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)}